# CT61 form for HMRC (corporation tax UK)

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, accounting, corporation

I recently created a company in the UK for occasional work as a locum pharmacist. I get paid by pharmacies for hours worked. Following advice from HMRC, I recently pulled out £500 of the company that I initially put into it from my private funds for various professional fees and expenses. I have registered with [PAYE](https://www.gov.uk/paye-online) and downloaded the 'BASIC PAYE TOOLS' app from HMRC. I haven't paid myself any wages yet, so all earnings are still in the company's account.

The HM Revenue and Customs recently sent me a prompt to complete a *CT61* form along with some [guiding notes](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/383833/ct61-notes-2010.pdf), which, despite having read them make no sense to me. Calling HMRC at tel.: 0300 200 3410 got me through to a what felt like a very inexperienced call handler who suggested I file CT61, yet he didn't sound at all confident what he was talking about. The CT61 form looks extremely confusing I don't want to pay an accountant to translate that gibberish for me for a hefty fee quite yet. I can't understand a single sentence of other related government guidelines, such as https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/company-taxation-manual/ctm35050.

Can someone be so kind as to explain in plain English (or German, Spanish or Hungarian, for that matter) what this CT61 is, and whether it applies to my situation outlined above? I was under the perhaps naive impression that I would get by by filing my accounts (with the help of an accountant) once a year and notify HMRC of payments I make to myself. Was I horribly wrong about that?

Comment: So you loaned your company money - a so-called ["director's loan"](https://www.gov.uk/directors-loans/you-lend-your-company-money)? Might HMRC think you are paying yourself interest on the loan?

Comment: Yes, I paid my company a loan, as described in your link above. The way I read the information there is that I wouldn't have to bother with a CT61, if I don't charge myself interest, which I don't. What I still don't understand is why, in the case interest is charged, the company must "pay you the interest less Income Tax at the basic rate of 20%" when the interest, if paid, is a business expense. I can't wrap my head around why the company (as opposed to the director) has to bother with income tax here.

Comment: it's probably an anti-avoidance measure - HMRC wants to make sure that the money doesn't end up completely untaxed with someone who then "forgets" to declare it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not entirely clear whether this CT61 applies to the situation above or not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not very sure either which is why I haven't tried to write an answer. My guess is that it doesn't.

Can you clarify what you mean by "Against advice from HMRC"? Does it mean they advised you not to do it? Or do you just mean you read some advice from HMRC and then did it? If the latter you should probably re-phrase as the wording implies the former.

Comment: Well, I initially asked the HMRC what would be involved in withdrawing the £500 from my company. They suggested I can just withdraw it without any further ado as this money had been taxed already. Maybe they thought better of it after the conversation.- Is there no one who has been in a similar situation before? There must be other folks who have a company and have lent it money.